# Can't connect to my Odoo server through the web browser

Tags: ubuntu, server, odoo-8

I recently installed **Odoo8** on **ubuntu 12.04 server** on a virtual machine (VMware workstation 10) but i can't connect remotely to the server using Google Chrome. I got either "Internal server error" or "This webpage is not available". I used ipaddress:8069 .Maybe I skipped a step during the configuration??

Comment: Do you see any error in the log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is that just look in to your log file to find the error. And try to solve it. May be it causes while installation interruption.